# Hacer sticky el slide mientras se hace scroll vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

**INTRO**

Estoy usando la libreria de swiper de js en un slider para que pase usando el scroll del ratón en vertical, este dato solo es relevante por saber que uso una librería que hace esta función.

**PROBLEMA**

> Necesito que este slider (el area gris) se mantenga sticky en la pagina, es decir, enganchado, porque se van a visualizar unos productos y se va a ver mientras se desliza todas las versiones del producto hasta llegar al final, es algo estetico que me han pedido, (aunque no sea muy util)
> , al terminar de hacer
> scroll, que siga con el funcionamiento normal de la página, de igual
> forma si subimos el slider en sentido contrario. Lo ideal es que se muestre el producto en esa sección hasta finalizar y seguir con otra sección e igual si volvemos hacia arriba de la página.

He añadido la librería sticksy-js (esta librería fija de forma absoluta un div mientras se visualiza, luego lo libera con un flex) y he conseguido mas o menos el efecto buscado pero no termina de ir fino, ciertamente con esta librería casi lo tendría me ayudaríais?¿

**EJEMPLO**

[ejemplo](https://www.zumex.com/exprimidoras/soul-series-2/)

[image: imagen de la maquina]

Tomamos como ejmeplo esta sección ya que sería algo parecido.

**CODIGO**

```js
const swiper1 = new Swiper(".swiper1", {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: "vertical",
  loop: false,
  speed: 1000,
  fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
  preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
  effect: "fade",
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  },
  // Use ResizeObserver (if supported by browser) on swiper container to detect container resize (instead of watching for window resize)
  resizeObserver: false,
  // Progress
  watchSlidesProgress: false,
  watchSlidesVisibility: false,
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    hide: false,
    draggable: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper {
    background-color: #848484;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 88vh;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: wheat;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;

}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #7f7e7e;
}
.container-slide {
    background-color: #8e8e8e;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: wheat;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}



.row.scrollFade h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade .texto-scroll {
    top: 8rem;
    }


.row.scrollFade img {
    width: 12rem;
    padding-bottom: 11rem;
  }
  
  .filler{
    display: flex;
  }


  /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .swiper {
        height: 93vh;
        padding-bottom: 0rem;
    }

    .row.scrollFade h3 {
        color: black;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .row.scrollFade p {
        color: black;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }
      
      .row.scrollFade .texto-scroll {
        top: 20rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        }
    

    .row.scrollFade img {
        width: 22rem;
        padding-left: 5rem;
      }
}


/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .swiper {
        height: 98vh;
        padding-bottom: 0rem;
    }

/*scroll slide */
.row.scrollFade h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade .texto-scroll {
      top: 16rem;
      padding-left: 23rem;
    }

    .row.scrollFade  img {
        width: 28rem;
        padding-left: 5rem;
      }

      .swiper-scrollbar-drag {
        background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.407);
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .swiper-scrollbar-drag:before {
        content: '';
        background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
        position: relative;
        left: -99.9vw;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0.7rem;
        z-index: 999;
      }
    
}
```

```html
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Swiper -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

    <!-- Sticky -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sticksy/dist/sticksy.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>

<!-- div de prueba -->

<div class=" gris">
      <div class="container  widget">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h2>titulo</h2>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

<!-- prueba scroll -->
<section class="">
<div class="swiper swiper1 widget js-sticky-widget">
 <!-- Add Scrollbar -->

 <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="First slide">
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="second slide">
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="Fourth slide">
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </section>
<!-- END prueba scroll -->

<div class="filler"></div>

<!-- div de prueba -->

<div class=" gris widget">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h2>titulo</h2>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/swiper.js"></script> 

  <script>
            var stickyEl = new Sticksy('.widget.js-sticky-widget', {
                topSpacing: 60,
            })
            stickyEl.onStateChanged = function (state) {
                if (state === 'fixed') stickyEl.nodeRef.classList.add('widget--sticky')
                else stickyEl.nodeRef.classList.remove('widget--sticky')
            }
        </script>
        </script>
     </body>
```

adjunto también el codigo en una pagina externa por si se visualiza mejor

[**CODIGO**](https://jsfiddle.net/azucarilla11/xem581kr/28/)

Tal vez esté usando mal alguna clase?

En las versiones de movil y tablet tampoco esta funcionando bien se salta la mitad del slide.

**LIBRERIAS**

Añado las librerías por si os es util para ayudarme.Las he estado consultando pero no me termino de aclarar.

- El pluggin de sticksy lo podeis encontrar [aquí](https://sticksy.js.org/)
- La API de swiper también estaría en este [enlace](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api)

**RESUMEN**

No me importa si no se usan estas librerías, si el efecto deseado es el mismo.

Debería quedar enganchada el area gris, mientras se visualiza hasta finalizar el slide o en caso de subir la página hasta llegar al inicio del slide.

Comment: Lo siento, pero no logro entender lo que buscas. Creo que tienes varias preguntas, cual es tu duda puntual?

Comment: @JheymanMejia disculpa creo que he divagado mucho haciendo la pregunta y al final no se ha entendido el concepto. Solo necesito que el slider hecho con swiper se mantenga sticky mientras se visualiza su contenido, tanto en moviles y tablets como en PC. Voy a editar la pregunta para que quede más claro lo que busco.

Comment: En tu código HTML hay etiquetas de cierre mal hubicados: `swiper-scrollbar` y otro más abajo. También las etiquetas `script` están mal acomodados; todos ellos deben ir al final de la página (en body), y en orden. Solamente las etiquetas `link ` de css van en `head`

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Me podrías indicar donde irian en un ejemplo? Gracias. En el ejemplo no he puesto ni head ni body, solo el codigo necesario, en mi código real si hay head y body y estas estan ubicadas en el lugar correspondiente. los scripts al final de body y los links en el head. lo que no termino de entender de tu respuesta es que te refieres a: "En tu código HTML hay etiquetas de cierre mal hubicados: swiper-scrollbar y otro más abajo."

Comment: Viendo tu código, parece que ya está listo, mas que todo resta ajustar el CSS.  ¿Porqué usas diferentes alturas? tienes height: 88vh, height:93vh y así varios. Deberías usar 100vh si quieres que el area gris ocupe todo el alto del dispositivo

Answer (score 1):

No se si esta solucion te va a servir, te comento lo que hice:

(en codepen se ve mejor que en el editor de SO, ademas adentro de los slides hay varias cosas que deben ser arregladas con CSS para que los textos se vean en todas las dimensiones, pero esos arreglos no vienen al caso)
https://codepen.io/agustinguerr4/pen/zYWQwYx

- primero los elementos que tenias en menos de 100vh, los lleve a 100vh en CSS para que ocupen todo el alto
- cambie "vertical" por "horizontal" en la config de tu swipper
- asigne un id `swiper1` al swiper
- guarde el elemento `swiper1` en la variable `element`.
- guarde la distancia de `swiper1` al top de la pagina en la variable `topElement`
- finalmente agregue un eventListener de cada vez que haces scroll, cuando el scroll se encuentre con el swiper, le va a agregar la posicion `fixed` para que quede fijo hasta que termines de scrollear.

Seguramente haya soluciones mejores, incluso aca vas a tener que encontrar el momento para remover el eventListener. Pero tal vez te sirva algo de la solucion para mejorarla.

Saludos

```js
const swiper1 = new Swiper(".swiper1", {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: "horizontal",
  loop: false,
  speed: 1000,
  fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
  preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
  effect: "fade",
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  },
  // Use ResizeObserver (if supported by browser) on swiper container to detect container resize (instead of watching for window resize)
  resizeObserver: false,
  // Progress
  watchSlidesProgress: false,
  watchSlidesVisibility: false,
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    hide: false,
    draggable: true,
  },
});
const element = document.getElementById("swiper1")
const topElement = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if(window.pageYOffset >= topElement){
    element.style.position = 'sticky'
  }
})
```

```css
.swiper {
    background-color: #848484;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: wheat;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;

}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #7f7e7e;
}
.container-slide {
    background-color: #8e8e8e;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: wheat;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}



.row.scrollFade h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade .texto-scroll {
    top: 8rem;
    }


.row.scrollFade img {
    width: 12rem;
    padding-bottom: 11rem;
  }
  
  .filler{
    display: flex;
  }


  /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .swiper {
        height: 100vh;
        padding-bottom: 0rem;
    }

    .row.scrollFade h3 {
        color: black;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .row.scrollFade p {
        color: black;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }
      
      .row.scrollFade .texto-scroll {
        top: 20rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        }
    

    .row.scrollFade img {
        width: 22rem;
        padding-left: 5rem;
      }
}


/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .swiper {
        height: 98vh;
        padding-bottom: 0rem;
    }

/*scroll slide */
.row.scrollFade h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }
  
  .row.scrollFade .texto-scroll {
      top: 16rem;
      padding-left: 23rem;
    }

    .row.scrollFade  img {
        width: 28rem;
        padding-left: 5rem;
      }

      .swiper-scrollbar-drag {
        background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.407);
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .swiper-scrollbar-drag:before {
        content: '';
        background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
        position: relative;
        left: -99.9vw;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0.7rem;
        z-index: 999;
      }
    
}
```

```html
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Swiper -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

    <!-- Sticky -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sticksy/dist/sticksy.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>

<!-- div de prueba -->

<div class=" gris">
      <div class="container  widget">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h2>titulo</h2>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

<!-- prueba scroll -->
<section class="">
<div class="swiper swiper1 widget js-sticky-widget" id="swiper1">
 <!-- Add Scrollbar -->

 <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="First slide">
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="second slide">
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="row scrollFade">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  texto-scroll">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
              <img class="img" alt="Fourth slide">
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </section>
<!-- END prueba scroll -->

<div class="filler"></div>

<!-- div de prueba -->

<div class=" gris widget">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h2>titulo</h2>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/swiper.js"></script> 

  <script>
            var stickyEl = new Sticksy('.widget.js-sticky-widget', {
                topSpacing: 60,
            })
            stickyEl.onStateChanged = function (state) {
                if (state === 'fixed') stickyEl.nodeRef.classList.add('widget--sticky')
                else stickyEl.nodeRef.classList.remove('widget--sticky')
            }
        </script>
        </script>
     </body>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por intentar ayudarme y responderme, voy a revisar lo que me comentas en tu respuesta.

Comment: He estado revisando, nos encontramos con el siguiente problema:  es que al visualizarlo con dispositivos moviles y hacer el gesto de pasar con el dedo, si no entramos especificamente en ese apartado pasará de largo, ya que es horizontal. Habria alguna forma que quedara atascado hasta terminar su visualización? si lo coloco vertical en moviles no avanzaría. Disculpa la molestia gracias! Agradezco muchisimo que hayas hecho el esfuerzo de intentar ayudarme!